# Browsing not working in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, internet-connection, anti-virus

I'm using Windows 8 Professional installed on Windows 7 using the "Save my preferences and apps" installation option.

The Windows works great, apps are downloading and I can listen to online radio stations using the TuneIn radio app meaning the internet connection is alive, however, when I open a browser (either Chrome or IE10) and try to browse the internet, I'm getting an "Unable to resolve DNS" error message. Prior to installing the internet browsing worked flawlessly I must say.

I'm using ESET NOD32 Antivirus so I suspect that it might interfere with the web connection now, but I'm not so sure. Internet options show that the PC is set to resolve the DNS automatically.

I don't know what to do. My other Win7 PCs in my wifi home network are connecting to the internet without any issues.

If anyone can help me resolve this I'll be grateful :) Thanks

EDIT: When writing "ping www.google.com" command in CMD, I get the IP of google resolved correctly, but when I try to input this same IP into the browser address bar, I get an error. It's worth to mention that I'm also using NOD32 Antivirus.

Comment: Perhaps, this is not the case, but check proxy settings in IE and make sure no proxy is configured there. Chrome uses settings from IE, that's explains why both browsers do not work.
Some malware can change proxy settings for you, so if this is the case - check PC for malware.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the proxy seems to be configured correctly (no proxy is set, the internet options are set to get the settings automatically)
I've talked to my ISP and I hope that I'll be able to fix it today. In the meanwhile I'm using my Win 7 laptop

Comment: Have you tried to disable NOD32 AV and firewall temporarily?

Comment: Yep, also didn't work :/

Comment: Try to telnet google.com 80, this will allow to check if HTTP is allowed at all. Blinking cursor means - allowed.
After that try resetting IE settings completely in Internet Options on Advanced Tab.

Comment: Telnet shows a blinking cursor, so I guess HTTP is allowed, but browsing is still not possible

Comment: Try Clean Boot or Safe Mode with networking, this is definitely some sort of local app is blocking access to the internet.
[Clean Boot](http://www.askdrtech.com/solutions/post/How-to-perform-a-clean-startup-(clean-boot)-in-Windows-7.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to my ISP, they suggested to write the following command in my CMD (you have to run the command prompt as an Administrator)

`netsh winsock r`

This will release the network resources. Once this is done, restart your PC and browsing is back!

Thanks to all the helpers! :) I hope this will save some time to other people who encounter this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It happends that a home router acts as a DNS server, assigns their own IP address as a DNS server, but fails to resolve DNS entries.

What if you change your DNS server settings manually on your windows machine (search for change adapter settings) to Google Public DNS servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4?

Comment: I saw this solution somewhere else and haven't tried it yet, I'll try this tonight and post my answer here. In any case, thanks for the response :)

Comment: I tried using those two addresses, no luck :/